# PL SQL substr: last n characters from smaller input

Tags: oracle, plsql, substr

*Situation:* I have to display the value (string) of a certain column in an output field. I want to show the last n characters of said value.

*Problem:* It may occur that the string has a length < n. In this case the return of substring is empty/NULL. This is strange and I would have expected to rather get all the characters of the string, maybe with added spaces. This is, I think, what happens in the case "substring from start position" (and not "from end position" like in my case).

*Code:*

```
dbms_output.put_line(substr(l_string, -n));
```

*Question:*

- Does someone see a reason for this behaviour?
- Is there a way to get the expected/wanted behaviour without using additional operations (like lpad/rpad/replace) every time?

(My best alternative for now would be to write it once in a variable and use that instead. But maybe some one knows something better.)

Comment: `dbms_output.put_line(substr(l_string, -least(n,length(l_string)));` should do it

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name, this seems to be the best way!
Do you happen to know a reason why substr does not behave the way I expect? I mean, since it works for substr-statements starting from the beginning or a given point, I find it somehow asymmetric that it behaves different if starting from the end of the string...